# Hudson + cppcheck, see all the errors for one file at once?

Tags: hudson

i'm currently configuring an hudson server with the cppcheck plugin. I'm trying to see all the errors/warnings associated with a file at the same time...however, i'm only able to see views of the files error by error.

Do you have any idea how to deal with that ?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In my hudson install, cppcheck creates the xml file that the plugin picks up and displays as a nice graph (of errors over time). If you click the graph you'll see a list of all the errors for all files in the project.

I do run cppcheck on the projects' directory so it recursively reads all files in there.

Comment: ok, but if you have several errors for the same file, you do have one entry per error ? (what i'd like is to have one entry per file with all the errors)